# How to select one word or paragraph in html without id

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

This is the first question of mine.
So if you feel inconvenience, please forgive me.
I'll very appreciate about your kindness.

I'm building an android application.
It contains android webview.

In android webview, a drag event of javascript doesn't work.
I think only touch and click events are working.

So I'd like to select word or paragraph like mouse drag.

When I search for this topic, many guys using id of element.
Like

```html
<p id="mytext">something</p>
```

But I'll use an android webview for whole sites like 'stackoverflow.com'

So I cannot use the way with element id.

Then, how can I select a word with click event.

Just for information, I want to use medium editor library in android webview.
https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor

Comment: what do you want ?

Comment: I want to know how can I select a word without element id using only one click.
Not using drag.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**  i hope your answer . **Select Any word then get select word without any id**

**Live Demo** [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/suhohusc/)

**Snippet Example**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    var p = $('p');
    p.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    p.click(function(e) {
        var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
        var word = $.trim(range.toString());
        if(word != '') {
            alert(word);
        }
        range.collapse();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>This is a paragraph</p>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you so much.

But if do this, I meet some troubles.

First, an uncaught typeerror is occur.
Accurately

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'collapse' on 'Selection': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.

The second problem is the code doesn't operate in one click.
It operates with drag.

There are something that I did wrong way?